# Где найти слайдер такого формата?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, вёрстка, slider

Как сделать его самостоятельно? Если есть ссылка, буду очень благодарен.

[image: Скриншот слайдера]

Comment: Вам нужно чтоб при нажатии на меньшую картинку перелистывалась большая?

Comment: примерно так...

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопросы о том, **где** найти программы или библиотеки не относятся к тематике нашего сайта.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это вариант со связкой большой и малой фото (на чистом JS):

```js
"use strict";
var gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');
var bImg = document.getElementById('b-img');
var minImgs = document.getElementById('min-imgs');
minImgs.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var target = e.target;
    
    if(target.classList.contains('img')){
        bImg.src = target.src; 
    }
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#gallery {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
.min-imgs {
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.min-imgs li {
    width: 30%;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
  <div id="gallery">
    <ul id="min-imgs" class="min-imgs">
      <li><img src="http://luxfon.com/large/201203/2608.jpg" class="img" alt="img"></li>
      <li><img src="http://luxfon.com/large/201203/8886.jpg" class="img" alt="img"></li>
      <li><img src="http://luxfon.com/large/201203/1341.jpg" class="img" alt="img"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="http://luxfon.com/large/201203/2608.jpg" alt="img" id="b-img">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Чуть, позже дополню и на jQuery, посмотрите сначала этот пример, тут принцип практически всех слайдеров.

Comment: `border` установил, чтоб вы понимали как регулируются границы слайдера, меняйте этот код, пробуйте вносить свои коррективы. Так быстрее поймете. `slick` очень хороший вариант тоже и многое там готово, но в первую очередь надо понимать как все работает на обычном JS, потом проще будет.

Comment: С плагинами хорошо, уже есть все готовое (сам ими пользуюсь часто), но в разработке могут возникнуть ситуации, где вы не сможете использовать jQuery (а большинство слайдеров типа `slick`, как раз таки на нем) и что тогда, как поступать?! Чистый JS никогда нельзя сбрасывать со счетов.

Answer (score 4):

Посмотрите в сторону slick slider.
Общий блок объявляете в js. 
Внутри делаете блок с картинкой и то, что справа.

> http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/