# Центрированный слайдер

Tags: slider

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, какой js-плагин использовать для создания такого слайдера?
Если возможно, предоставьте ссылку на пример кода.
Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: slick-slider или самостоятельно написать. 2-й вариант лучше.

Comment: Какой именно вид slick слайдера выбрать?

Comment: Это уже вам виднее, зайдите на сайт плагина и посмотрите на тот который вам подходит.

Comment: Прям такой как у вас на фото я как-то использовал в MaterializeCSS, там точно такой был. Правда по дефолту был без стрелок, но это там быстро лечится

Comment: Скорее всего и в Bootstrap есть, да тьма этих плагинов на jQuery готовых есть в интернете. Проще всего написать свой, как я говорил, не будете привязаны к плагину. Ну в любом случае, устанавливаете плагин, если не разбираетесь и лезете под капот, смотрите что там к чему, меняете. Как правило везде написаны адекватные доки. О, и [вот тут карусель MeterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/carousel.html)

Comment: Кстати вспомнил, [вот тут я как-то делился мыслями как пишется слайдер на чистом JS без jQuery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/772939/%d0%93%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0/772982#772982), изучите его, может поможет вам понять что к чему.