# Подскажите хороший слайдер

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Нужен слайдер, где будет отображаться три окна и при клике на <kbd>PREV</kbd> <kbd>NEXT</kbd> будут внутри трёх окон меняться картинки. Размеры окон разные: будут картинки для десктопа, для планшета и для мобильных устройств - соответственно размеры окна и картинки для десктопа должна быть самыми большими, для планшета - средняя, для телефона - маленькая. Важно то, чтобы при клике на <kbd>PREV</kbd> <kbd>NEXT</kbd> три картинки скрывались за пределы своих трёх окон...

Comment: Slick slider ищите

Comment: Связанный: [Где найти слайдер такого формата?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/772939/262779)

Comment: @ArturHan , slick пробовали уже - не подходит :(

Comment: Что значит не подходит?это движок слайдера. Стилизуйте его под свои нужды

Comment: вот выберите какой душа пожелает https://www.jqueryscript.net/plus/search.php?kwtype=0&keyword=slider

Comment: @ArturHan , может я запрос чуток непонятно задал: в обычных слайдерах, и в slike в том числе, слайдятся картинки справо-налево/или наоборот по одной/или по сколько задаю одного размера, а мне надо чтобы в одной строке было три окна, которые будут разного размера - в моём случае три размера, и в этих окнах менялись картинки по клику на PREV-NEXT - т.е. я один раз кликаю на кнопку и в каждом окне меняется своя картинка, но окна с разной тематикой(одно окно - скрин десктопа, во втором окне - скрин планшета, в третьем - скрин мобилки)

Comment: Действительно,непонятно.лучше нарисуйте

Comment: Я думаю,что даже здесь можно сделать три slick-слайдера,расположенных горизонтально. Каждое окно-отдельный слайдер

Comment: @ArturHan , http://prntscr.com/m3etk1   -  вот - при клике на стрелочку картинки должны меняться только внутри окон 1-2-3  --- в каждом из этих окон будут картинки, которые не должны повторяться в остальных окнах, т.е. картинки для десктопа не должны отображаться в окне для планшета и в окне для мобилок при клике на стрелочку PREV-NEXT

Comment: Щас напишу ответ

Comment: Где код?  Какие слайдеры Вы уже искали и пробовали?  Почему не подходит slick slider?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
$('.slider ul').each(function(){
  $(this).children().eq(0).addClass('active');
});
$('.left').click(function() {
  $('ul').each(function() {
    var slide = Number($(this).children('.active').attr('id').split('-')[2]);
    var slider = $(this).children('.active').attr('id').split('-')[1];
    $(this).children().removeClass('active');
    if (slide == 1) $(this).children('#slide-' + slider + '-2').addClass('active');
    else if (slide == 2) $(this).children('#slide-' + slider + '-3').addClass('active');
    else if (slide == 3) $(this).children('#slide-' + slider + '-1').addClass('active');
  });
});
$('.right').click(function() {
  $('ul').each(function() {
    var slide = Number($(this).children('.active').attr('id').split('-')[2]);
    var slider = $(this).children('.active').attr('id').split('-')[1];
    $(this).children().removeClass('active');
    if (slide == 1) $(this).children('#slide-' + slider + '-3').addClass('active');
    else if (slide == 2) $(this).children('#slide-' + slider + '-1').addClass('active');
    else if (slide == 3) $(this).children('#slide-' + slider + '-2').addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.slider {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width:500px;
}
.slider ul{
 border:1px solid black;
}
.slider ul:nth-child(1),
.slider ul:nth-child(3) {
  width: 20%;
  Height: 100px;
}

.slider ul:nth-child(2) {
  width: 40%;
  height: 200px;
}

.slider span {
  width: 5%;
}

.active {
  display: block!important;
}

.slider li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="slider">
  <span class="left"> Влево</span>
  <ul class="slider-1">
    <li id="slide-1-1">slide1.1</li>
    <li id="slide-1-2">slide1.2</li>
    <li id="slide-1-3">slide1.3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="slider-2">
    <li id="slide-2-1">slide2.1</li>
    <li id="slide-2-2">slide2.2</li>
    <li id="slide-2-3">slide2.3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="slider-3">
    <li id="slide-3-1">slide3.1</li>
    <li id="slide-3-2">slide3.2</li>
    <li id="slide-3-3">slide3.3</li>
  </ul>
  <span class="right"> Вправо</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Добрый день, у меня выскочила ошибка: "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).children.eq is not a function"  -  гугл мне не помог(, подскажите, плз., как "убрать" эту ошибку?. спс

Comment: Я там подправил. Исправьте на children(). Скобки добавьте

Comment: а почему теперь может ругаться на 'split' (( ? - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined  -  это когда кликаешь на кнопки "Влево"-"Вправо"

Comment: А вы завернули скрипт в document.ready?

Comment: исправил. Там addclass('active') без точки надо

Comment: да, завернул, но теперь слайдится только первый слайдер и по-прежнему в консоли ошибка: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"  и не отрабатывают два других слайдера.

Comment: Нее, вы еще раз код скопируйте. Я там во всех функцциях addclass исправил

Comment: Сработало!!!Спасибо...а как можно анимированно это сделать?а то в стилях transition добавил, но это не помогло - оно очень резко и быстро переключается...

Comment: в стилях в класс active transition добавили?

Comment: да, добавил стили, но оно не помогло - я уже почти везде...наверное в самом скрипте надо куда-то вставить animation...Вы не подскажите куда? или может вместо removeClass и addClass hide/show как-то вставлять?

Comment: Можно в css через keyframes погуглите